Econometrics bounds question
I recently ran into a presentation where the following slide was introduced.

now to give a little context we are dealing with a selection bias issue where we observe only outputs YS. Specifically, consider that W = (X, Y, S, YS, D) where X are covariates, Y is the outcome, S is a selection indicator, YS is the observed "selected" outcome, and D is the treatment indicator. \eta_0 is a nuisance parameter and the goal of the procedure is to estimate the upper and lower bounds for the CATE (conditional average treatment effect). Z is a low-dimensional summary measure such that Zi = f(Xi). Now in the slides what we see is basically o the first equation the CATE multiplied by the density of the always takers (s(0,z)) and the expression of the density of always takers in the second equation. Now, my doubt is how can orthogonal moment function \psi_{S0} identify s(0,z) and in what sense orthogonal moment function \psi_{B} identifies scaled unconditional bound.
I mean the two equations are kind of confusing to me. Any hint is appreciated.
Thank you in advance.
